# How to store auth data for RESTful API

Tags: angular, rest, authentication, restful-authentication

I am developing an Angular application that consumes a RESTful API. Authentication is done with a basic HTTP Authorization header.

What is the best practice to store the credential to be send with each request? As it is RESTful - stateless, there is no cookie nor token. Except the local storage, I see no solution, and I don't like it as it may be stolen with JS injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in localstorage encrypted:

1. Encrypt your response
2. Store it in localStorage
3. Decrypt value from localStorage if you want to use it

Comment: Encryption key must be stored in the browser, so any attacker would be allowed to decrypt the credential, wouldn't he?

Comment: What about encrypting it in the API?. I'm just trying to think of a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cookie!
That is done with the secure cookies.

```
signUp(email: string, password: string, passwordConfirm: string, name: string): Observable<User> {
    const url = `${this.BASE_URL}/users/signup`;
    return this.http.post<User>(url, {email, password, passwordConfirm, name}, {
      withCredentials: true, // this part is very important
    });
  }
```

```
//Node js 
const createAndSendToken = (user, statusCode, req,res) => {
  const token = signToken(user._id, user.name);
  const cookieOptions =  { 
    expires: new Date(
      Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
      ),
      httpOnly: true
  }

  // if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') cookieOptions.secure = true;

  if(req.secure || req.headers('x-forwarded-proto') === 'https') cookieOptions.secure = true; //this part is for heroku, it's important to have secure option set to true inside cookieOptions

  res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);
  
  user.password = undefined;

  res.status(statusCode).json({
    status: 'success',
    token,
    data: {
      user
    }
  })
}
```

After that inside you set the cors options only for one origin and credentials needs to be true.
Connection must go over https protocol. If everything works fine cookie will be stored automatically. Open console then Application under Storage you have Cookies and check if there is a cookie. On every request you will have access to cookie inside Rest Api

```
exports.isLoggedIn = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.cookies.jwt) {
    try {
  // 1) Verification token
  const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(req.cookies.jwt, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
  
  // 2) Check if user still exists
  const currentUser = await User.findById(decoded.id);
  
  if(!currentUser) {
    return next();
  }

  // 4) Check if user changed password after the token was issued
  if(currentUser.changedPasswordAfter(decoded.iat)) {
    return next()
  }
  //THERE IS A LOGGED IN USER
  req.user = currentUser;
  return next();  

  } catch(err) {

    return next();
  }   
    
  }
  next();
}
```

On every reload inside angular application we are calling this function.